# numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, windows-8.1, pycharm

While installing SciPy on PyCharm IDE, I got stuck with the error saying

> numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

I have installed correct version of pip. I don't know where went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)

Answer (score 3):

[Blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) are linear algebra packages which will need to be installed before scipy will work (check the dependencies). For windows 8.1 you may find help on http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/.

Also check out this answer which may help [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)