# Python packaging: wheels vs tarball (tar.gz)

Tags: python, tar, packaging, python-wheel

The advantage of wheels over eggs is clear (see section why not egg? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel).

However, it is not entirely clear to me what is the advantage of using wheels over `tar.gz`. I might be missing something obvious like "they are the same". 
As I see it both can be installed directly using `pip` (even in Windows), have similar size and when packaging require a similar effort. 
It sounds to me like the kind of questions you might get when justifying a packaging methodology.

EDIT:
Just found an example where `tar.gz` might be better than wheels. CherryPy (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CherryPy) provides wheels for Python 3.x only, so if you want to have a local repository to serve CherryPy for Python 2.7 and 3.x dependencies, it seems to make more sense to store the tarball. Is this correct? (just to add a couple of "case-based" justification to the discussion)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This answered it for me (directly from the wheel PEP):

> Python needs a package format that is easier to install than sdist.
>   Python's sdist packages are defined by and require the distutils and
>   setuptools build systems, running arbitrary code to build-and-install,
>   and re-compile, code just so it can be installed into a new
>   virtualenv. This system of conflating build-install is slow, hard to
>   maintain, and hinders innovation in both build systems and installers.
>
> Wheel attempts to remedy these problems by providing a simpler
>   interface between the build system and the installer. The wheel binary
>   package format frees installers from having to know about the build
>   system, saves time by amortizing compile time over many installations,
>   and removes the need to install a build system in the target
>   environment.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#rationale

Note the tarballs we're speaking of are what are referred to as "sdists" above.

Comment: thanks, i was trying to read the setuptools documentation, and didn't understand the following sentence `the 'tests' directory will be present in the 'sdist' but not in the 'wheel'`  now I know that the `tar.gz` files are the `sdist` and the `.whl` files are the "wheels"

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html

Answer (score 12):

From [Python Wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/)

> **Advantages of wheels**
>
> • Faster installation for pure python and native C extension packages.
> • Avoids arbitrary code execution for installation. (Avoids setup.py)
> • Installation of a C extension does not require a compiler on Windows or OS X.
> • Allows better caching for testing and continuous integration.
> • Creates .pyc files as part of installation to ensure they match the python interpreter used.
> • More consistent installs across platforms and machines.

Make sure wheel is installed.

```
python3 -m pip install wheel
```

Comment: are all those points things that tarballs cannot do? (I could easily say that you need "extra" software for wheels in a linux machine while tarball wouldn't for example)

Comment: I don't always know what's in a tarball, even by opening the archive, to the same degree that I know what's in a .whl file which is supposed to "just work", and that's a big advantage to me when using pip which often doesn't "just work".

Comment: Could you go a bit deeper on that point? as I see it, when I look at a wheel and a tarball, both have the package zipped inside and some extra magic for packaging. Even I could say that in the tarball I can see the license right there while I can't find it in the wheel (quite an important point when doing commercial softwr). Both could hide something undesirable, that's why I don't get the "just work". (BTW, I like wheels but I need a solid justification)

Comment: @zom-pro: as far as I understand, the files in a wheel are just copied into place. The files in a sdist archive are processed with `setup.py` -- which normally just copies them somewhere, but it doesn't have to just copy them. So a wheel is simpler in this sense.