# error while installing scipy module in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, lapack

I'm trying to install scipy module in python using pip...it is showing following error..

```
Command "c:\users\sony\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe 
-u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\sony\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
vmyvqdgv\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --
record C:\Users\sony\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mf_0tla_-record\install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error
code 1 in C:\Users\sony\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-vmyvqdgv\scipy\
```

and when I tried it using easy_install, it showed:

```
error: no lapack/blas resources found
```

Any solutions please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found

Answer (score 1):

1. First install Numpy+MKL by downloading wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).
2. Go to your .whl file location and type `pip install <filename>`
3. Now download SciPy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy).
4. Repeat step 2.

Note: Upgrade pip first by `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing scipy separately install anaconda(windows setup available) which comes with scipy numpy pandas and other useful python modules. https://www.continuum.io/downloads This will ease your future tasks as well when install other required modules as it creates a separate environment