# SKLearn and Scipy not installing thorugh pip with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I am trying to install sklearn, and hitting wall after wall. When I first tried to install it through pip, it started flipping out about scipy. I went and installed the scipy wheel file, and the numpy+mkl wheel file after that. After some more errors and such, I tried reinstalling everything. Still nope. Tried updating setuptools just to be sure, still nope. This time, I try again and after considerable time and a huge wall of text, if stops with this error:

```
Command "C:\Users\ZackPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe 
-u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ZackPC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
gowcc39f\\scikit-learn\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ZackPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
_y2kd8u6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ZackPC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
build-gowcc39f\scikit-learn\
```

Searching this error gets me right back to one of the beginning threads I searched through, [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700439/error-while-installing-scipy-module-in-python) which has a similar error. I've tried pretty much everything in there to no avail. Anybody have ideas?

Comment: is there any reason you're using 3.6 which is fresh and might introduce some issues with 3rd party libraries? Have you tried the same thing with Python 3.5?

Comment: Yep, I originally had 3.5 installed and got 3.6 when I reinstalled everything fresh.

Comment: So the issue is also there with `3.5` too, right?

Comment: The issue is there with 3.5, yes.

Comment: has anyone found a solution for python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda is the easiest solution. I recall before I used anaconda that you can't include scipy and numpy in the same requirements file as each depends on the other so you have to install them in the right sequence. Then there were other errors around versions of linalg and other packages; and of course it takes forever to compile them.