# Unable to install Statsmodels...python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, pip, statsmodels

I am using 32 bit cmd, 64 bit windows, python 2.7

when I type the command pip install statsmodels

I get the following error for some module of scipy...

```
Failed building wheel for Scipy Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
```

[image]

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found also this https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/

Comment: So for installing LAPACK for windows 8 do I need to have Visual Studio

Comment: Use a package like conda/anaconda or winpython or use the gohlke binaries. Trying to compile scipy on Windows (which also requires a Fortran compiler) is just a waste of time unless you're an expert.

Comment: don't copy images of text please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

install numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

If you face installation issues for numpy, get the pre-built windows installers from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for your python version (python version is different from windows version).

numpy 32-bit: numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

numpy 64-bit: numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Later you require VC++ 9.0, then please get it from below link Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Then install

Get the pre-built windows installers from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for your python version (python version is different from windows version).

Scipy 32-bit: scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

Scipy 64-bit: scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

If it fails saying whl is not supported wheel on this platform , then upgrade pip using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and try installing scipy

Now try

```
pip install scipy
```

Then try

```
pip install statsmodels
```

It should work like a charm

Comment: @Shank please use proper spelling, grammar, and punctuation.

Comment: I'm getting  "Cython is required to compile statsmodels from a development branch. Please install Cython or download a source release of statsmodels." error. Strange thing is I've already installed Cython.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried to write this on cmd.exe and it worked.

```
pip install statsmodels==0.6.0
```

[install statsmodels for python 2.7 in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTJyS.png)

Comment: Worked for me .

Answer (score 5):

An easier way to install python libraries on Windows with C/C++/Fortran/... dependencies is to use `conda`. `conda` is available in [MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows) continuum products.

Another easy way to install scientific python libraries on windows is to use [Christoph Gohlke's windows web page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

If you have no much idea about all of them and how to manage dependencies on windows I recommend you uninstalling your Python and installing anaconda. Anaconda already has Numpy, Scipy, Matplotlib,..., and statsmodels [pre-installed (see the list of the packages included in the anaconda distribution)](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs).

Comment: I dont have c/c++/fortran/ on my pc.... I just want to run regression and thought statsmodels.api is the best  somehow pandas.stats.api is also giving error

Comment: You don't need it, Anaconda deals with that for you :-D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version of **pip** 
To check which version you are using try:

```
pip --version
```

To install statsmodels you can either go to cmd.exe or if you are using python pycharm use "Terminal Window" and type:

```
pip install statsmodels==0.9.0
```