# Error when trying to pip install statsmodels

Tags: python, numpy, installation, statsmodels

I am getting the attached error when trying to pip install statsmodels using Python 3.6.3. Please see link for error.

**screenshot**

[image]

I saw a previous similar question was answered and the solution was simply 
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
then finally pip install statsmodels

[Unable to install Statsmodels...python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792043/unable-to-install-statsmodels-python)

I already have numpy and scipy successfully installed. Any other recommendations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem it got solved.Since python 3.6 may not support some dependencies and its in research phase i recommend you to use python 2.7.11 and try pip install statsmodels 
There might be some error regarding visual c++ please download it to clear the process....(I had error saying visual c++ 14.0 python 2.7)

Comment: Python 3.6 is certainly stable.