# How can I install statsmodels?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install statsmodes on my local machine using `pip install statsmodels` and I keep getting the following error:

`ERROR: Failed building wheel for statsmodels`

I've tried installing the C++ Visual Studio Compiler and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: See this. This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792043/unable-to-install-statsmodels-python

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `pip` using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Install `scipy` using `pip install scipy`

And, then try installing `statsmodel`

```
pip install statsmodels
```