# PIP Install Statsmodels failed with exit code 1120

Tags: c++, pip, statsmodels

I have been attempting to download the statsmodels package all day with no luck. I have downloaded the most recent C++ build tools and believe everything is downloaded correctly. When I attempt to pip install statsmodels, I am returned the following error message below. I have also attempted to run **pip install statsmodels==0.6.0** which returns with exit status of **2**. Not really sure what I can do except uninstall python and c++ build tools then re download. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
set build\lib.win32-3.7\statsmodels/_version.py to '0.10.0'
running build_ext
   Creating library build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\statsmodels/tsa/innovations\_arma_innovations.cp37-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\statsmodels/tsa/innovations\_arma_innovations.cp37-win32.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common
build\lib.win32-3.7\statsmodels\tsa\innovations\_arma_innovations.cp37-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\\users\\dp1069\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\lib /LIBPATH:c:\users\dp1069\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\dp1069\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\PCbuild\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\ATLMFC\lib\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\lib\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64 npymath.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__arma_innovations build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\statsmodels/tsa/innovations/_arma_innovations.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.7\statsmodels\tsa\innovations\_arma_innovations.cp37-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\statsmodels/tsa/innovations\_arma_innovations.cp37-win32.lib" failed with exit status 1120

Command "c:\users\dp1069\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\dp1069\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qd4q52qu\\statsmodels\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\dp1069\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dhpbb7se\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dp1069\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qd4q52qu\statsmodels\
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>
```

Comment: What stands out is `"LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library"` While this is a tool exclusively related (from what I can tell), it is a valid question on S.O. However, since it is also, at its core, a `"How do I install xyz?"` question, you may receive more help on the StackExchange site [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Pasting your title into a general search engine discloses the duplicate question [Unable to install Statsmodels…python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792043/unable-to-install-statsmodels-python) (seems `numpy` is needed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Statsmodels...python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792043/unable-to-install-statsmodels-python)

Answer (score 1):

For all of those that may come across this issue and have all of the dependency packages already installed, the solution was quite simple. Navigate to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ , find your package and follow instructions to download the package via python wheel.