# change homebrew python3.9 to python 3.8/python 3.7

Tags: python, plotly, homebrew, statsmodels, trendline

Context: I was doing a plotly dash project. Trendline='ols' was not working. Had to install statsmodel.

1. change my python 2.7 to python 3.9 using a youtube homebrew python 3 tutorial. I edited my zshrc and all that jazz. https://youtu.be/0rg6nyanX5Y
2. Then I did pip install statsmodel, error occurred. So I used this guide [Unable to install Statsmodels...python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792043/unable-to-install-statsmodels-python).
   I did pip install numpy, no problem.
   I did pip install scipy, theres an issue.
   I did pip install statsmodels, theres an issue.
3. Then I went thorough a rabbit hole of googling how to change homebrew python 3.9 to python 3.8.
4. I think I messed up my python homebrew configuration.
5. Someone save me.... I just want to run Trendline='ols' on my school plotly dash project... :(

Comment: what is the error you get when installing statsmodels? This is not very clear