# I can`t install scipy on Windows 10(Visual studio 2017RC) with pip

Tags: python, scipy

I had the problem that scipy always fails to install on my pc (Win10) even after I reinstalled python and Visual studio. It would be nice if someone could help me.

```
Collecting scipy==0.18.1
  Using cached scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy: started
    Running setup.py install for scipy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" -u -c 
      "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='...\scipy\\setup.py';
      f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
      code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
      f.close();
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
      install --record ...\install-record.txt 
      --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib',
    'C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib',
    'C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: 
UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-
          builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532:
UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib',
    'C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543: 
UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546: 
UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v51ssklt\scipy\setup.py", 
    line 415, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v51ssklt\scipy\setup.py", 
    line 411, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", 
    line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v51ssklt\scipy\setup.py", 
    line 335, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", 
    line 1000, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", 
    line 969, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", 
    line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", 
    line 1000, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", 
    line 969, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", 
    line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" -u -c 
  "import setuptools, tokenize;
  __file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-v51ssklt\\scipy\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install 
--record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p9s2pvsd-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed
--compile" failed with error code 1 in 
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v51ssklt\scipy\
----- Failed to install 'scipy==0.18.1' -----
```

(installing numpy works fine) Can someone help me ?

Comment: This might be relevant (no promises) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can!

Manually download the hand-rolled wheel suitable for your system here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

From your output it looks like you're on Python 3.5 (64-bit), you you will be looking to download this **scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl**

Save it (e.g. C:/temp/scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl or whatever)

Then do "Python Environments">Python 3.5>right click "pip install"

paste "C:/temp/scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl" and hit enter.

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from scipy==0.19.0)
  Installing collected packages: scipy
  Successfully installed scipy-0.19.0

Comment: this worked for me `(py35) C:\Users\mona6\Downloads>pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\mona6\downloads\scipy-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from scipy==0.19.0)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-0.19.0`