# Scipy stack installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to install the Scipy stack on windows 8.1 numpy installs perfectly but after that the scipy gives the following error 
[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1CHH.png)

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: It's getting on my nerves. https://linusgroh.de/programming-issue-google-it

Comment: For Windows it's a pain. `pip install wheel` (iirc) and then just download these libraries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). Get `numpy` with MLK and download the extra libraries after that

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found), which I found by googling your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)

Comment: @upvoter there's zero efford in the question, and its a dup by the way. Why would one ever upvote this crap?

Comment: @linusg As for your first message, I hear you :) But on Windows, the SciPy stack is actually pretty difficult to install. I have scanned your dupe and I don't see how it is better than the binaries

Comment: @linusg I even use Enthought Canopy. It still fell apart for me.

Comment: @roganjosh - Totally agree. Im not a Windows User anymore (Linux is *much* better here), but I managed installing all the numpy/scypi stuff on Win by downloading the Binaries there too. The site is pretty useful :)

Comment: @linusg if there were zero effort in doing so i would have done it myself no need for asking and by the way if you are not up for helping someone then don't even look at it :p and don't tire your fingers on writing the comment :p happy life bro ;)

Comment: As one said in the comments, this could be solved by simpy looking the error up on Google. Where's the efford? I can't see any... And your comment is not helpful at all. I'm here to help people, but not to answer questions asked before several times (and which can be solved by GOOGLEING)

Comment: To OP: don't even bother trying to install via `pip`, you will find peace in using the binaries I linked :) @linusg it's not worth getting frustrated mate, this will always exist but don't let it reflect badly on you if you ever want to use your profile in recruitment

Comment: @roganjosh - Kind words, thanks. However, this sort of question is around too much here in the last time. But right, don't get frustrated, go on with the serious questions :)

Comment: @linusg peace bro beginners do this kinda stuff and i am a beginner so just chill you people are more experienced so thats why people post here to get some good answers and suggestion but any way thank you for your kind advice and thanks for the ans -roganjosh

Comment: I've fallen foul of this myself. It _is_ frustrating for the same kind of questions to come up, but the solution is not always easy to find yourself when you first start out. Open a command prompt in the `downloads` directory (open it as normal in Windows, hold down `shift` and right click) and `pip install the_downloaded_file_name` here once you download the binary.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help @roganjosh i really appreciate your help God bless you :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe Scipy has some weird dependencies that need time and attention to configure properly. So it would be your best route to install the anaconda suite which has much more than scipy and numpy.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows