# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lapack/blas

Tags: python, numpy, pip, lapack, blas

I am using python3, pip3 and have already installed numpy, but when trying to download Scipy (I need to install sklearn), I am getting this error

```
raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources not found
```

when trying to install lapack/blas:

```
    Collecting lapack..
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blas (from versions:)
    No matching distribution found for blas
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 8.1 -64 bit but I have installed python 32bit -Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found). Essentially, if you've installed `numpy` through PIP on Windows, it doesn't take care of these dependencies. My advice would to use the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows), and not really related, but definitely use 64bit Python if you *can*.