# Installation of SciPy and mkl

Tags: python, scipy, intel-mkl

I have tried  to install Scipy along with MKL. I have tried installing Scipy using pip(`pip install scipy`). Following is the error message that I get.

```
 lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
  pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\intern\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yusrir\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "c:\users\intern\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yusrir\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "c:\users\intern\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yusrir\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
```

From this message I understand that I have not installed MKL library and therefore I try to install mkl by the following command.

`pip install mkl`

Following is the message that I get for this.

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mkl`

I also tried to download the appropriate mkl wheel file from [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) link and install using pip(`pip install numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`). Following is the error message that I get.

`numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I also have made sure that all the files that I have downloaded are appropriate. My system is 64 bit and I have installed python 2.7.
Can you suggest what am I doing wrong here? Is there any other possibility for installation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: this thread might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860484/5206831