# This is the error that I am getting while executing from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/12.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this package using:

```
easy_install scipy
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

or

```
pip install scipy
```

or

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

if you are using windows refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39577864/6633975

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064281/6633975

Comment: 'scipy' is not even installing & giving me the error as 'no lapack/blas resources found' in command prompt.I am using python 2.7 version.Is that the reason?Please..

Comment: @PremKumar have you searched for that error? Have you made *any* attempt to debug this yourself before posting on SO?

Comment: @PremKumar are you using windows os?

Comment: 'scipy' package is installed properly after referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064281/6633975. Thankyou.