# How to install packages (or use existing packages) for C:\Python27 when these are already installed in C:\path\Anaconda3\...?

Tags: python, package

*Please consider: I am not a CS-person, and have limited experience with path variables, global environments etc. However, please let me know if my problem can be fixed by adding a new path variable for Python27. BTW, I am using Windows10.*

On my PC I have Anaconda downloaded with python3, Jupyter, spyder etc...

Anaconda is convenient and the CMD-command "python" will start

*Python 3.6.0 | Anaconda 4.3.1*

Running Python36 is not a problem, and the Anaconda distribution contains everything I need for using Python. However, I would also like to be able to import (or use existing) packages for the Python27 interpreter which I have downloaded independently from the python.org site. Running the command

```
(CMD) > pip install scipy
```

returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

Running the command in Python27

```
>>> from scipy import *
```

returns

```
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Please understand my problem: I wish to keep my Anaconda - python 3x distribution, but in addition I would also like to be able to use python 2x in full extent (all packages)

Comment: In your cmd shell, type "where pip". I think you're using the pip for the anaconda install, so look through the "where" output and look for a pip.exe in the Python 2 source tree. Then retry the pip install using the full path to the other pip exe. This is probably something like "c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install scipy"

Comment: @Kev: thank you. Now I am able to install numpy, sympy, matplotlib etc... I get problems with the scipy, where PIP raises a "NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')... Do you know a quickfix ?

Comment: the error means that pip is trying to find lapack/blas that scipy is dependent on but can't. You might want to have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found which discusses this

Comment: @Kev: You helped me a lot... I finally got it right

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am going to share what I have done to install **scipy**.

> MY PC Configuration is `windows-7 64-bit & python 2.7`

- **First**  I download  the required packages form  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (which version match your configuration EX: cp27==>python2.7 & cp36==>3.6)
- **Second**  I extract the file using `7zip` (also can be used any zipper like winrar)
- **Third** I copy the `scipy` folder which I extracted and paste it into `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` (or put it where the exact location is in your PC like `..\..\Lib\site-packages`)

> NOTE: Have to install **numpy** `first` before installing **scipy** in this same way.