# Installing SciPy on windows

Tags: python, windows, scipy, installation

I have problems with installing SciPy on windows. I've already tried `pip install` (which worked for NumPy) but it didn't work out. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you gotten any errors when installing? We'll need a bit more info.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which is a binary distribution system, which means that you don't need to compile yourself. Overall I find this to be a far easier way to handle packages on windows.

Using Anaconda, you can install scipy via:

```
conda install scipy
```

Comment: Anaconda is clearly the best choice for unexperienced users in Python and Windows.

Comment: Worked out! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

A good way with those kind of packages (scipy, numpy, ...) on Windows is to download (unoficial) binaries from this [website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and install it from here.

Once download, you can install it using pip :

```
pip install scipy-package.whl
```