# Pip fails to install SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, pip, failed-installation

I have been trying to install SciPy through pip with `pip install scipy` but it gives me the error `Failed building wheel for scipy`, promptly followed by `Failed cleaning build dir for scipy`.

I have tried upgrading pip through `pip install --upgrade pip` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip), installing it through anaconda as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485399/installing-scipy-on-windows) as well as the solutions suggested by pip. Those solutions being:

```
- `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
- `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                    files that aren't checked into the git repo)
```

And:

```
- `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
- `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)
```

When I try to upgrade pip it gives:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

When I try to install it through anaconda Windows gives: `The program has stopped responding`.

All help is appreciated and please feel free to leave a comment telling me is there is more information needed to help solve this issue. I am using Windows 10 as well as Python 3.6.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing SciPy on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485399/installing-scipy-on-windows)

Comment: I have tried installing it through anaconda (which I use for spyder) and it still failed

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pip` and try again or possibly `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: How did it fail with conda?

Comment: I get that the program has stopped responding

Comment: If it's trying to build a wheel, it does sound like it's trying to build native binaries from scratch. It noteably doesn'ts seem to have a Windows build [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy). Have you tried downloading and installing the [unofficial binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)? (That page is a *godsend* for Windows users. No exaggeration.)

Comment: I just tried that and got the same issue. I did take longer for me to get the error (as in it was just slower) which got my hopes up but it ended up failing.

Comment: @LiamHealy I'm suspicious that something might have gotten partially done, effectively corrupting your local install. Try two things: look into site-packages and see if there's garbage there, and see if it will install in a clean virtualenv.

Comment: The "failed cleaning build dir" might also indicate some temp files need to be deleted, as well, but I couldn't tell you where they would be.

Comment: I got a new error when trying the unofficial binaries: `scipy-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: `cp27` means it's a CPython 2.7 wheel. You need one of the `cp36` wheels. Make sure you pick the correct one for 64 or 32 bit, too. (`amd64` is the 64 bit one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [jpmc26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) in the comments for the solution:

- You need to install the unofficial binary from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
- To install it, execute: `pip install C://Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Downloads/SCIPY_FILE`
- Make sure you use the correct version for your system (32 bit vs 64 bit) and for your Python version
- You also need to look into site-packages and see if there's garbage there. If there is, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that issue before, and my resolution was to install needed dependencies. I seem to recall `scipy` requires `numpy` to be installed first. Perhaps try `pip install numpy` first?

The [SciPy install page](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) shows this:

```
pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

Comment: I already have numpy installed: `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages`

Comment: As for the scipy install page recommendation it installed all the stuff I didn't have before but gave me the same scipy error: `Failed building wheel for scipy` and `Failed cleaning build dir for scipy`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled as well trying to create a backwards compatible environment for some older tutorial scripts.  I needed **Scipy==0.18.2**. So I searched on [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org) and found:
`conda install -c esri scipy`
This worked without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to download the package via the following link:
https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files

install this file through pip install: you can see
[install downloaded package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFvYU.png)