# statsmodels installation: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

It seems to be a common problem but none of the answers seems help. The error is popping up when installing `statsmodels` with in Windows 10 (python 3.6.2 installed):

```
python setup.py install
```

Before that, `numpy` has been installed:

```
python numpy install
```

There was no error and I assume it was a success.But the installation of `statsmodels` still have the error with `statsmodels` installation.

I did install MS c++ compiler (2015). Also I installed latest Anaconda (python 3.6.1) and it did not help. The following is a list of VC++ compilers installed.

[image]

Comment: Did you download the source from github or pypi?

Comment: `statsmodels` was from github as I remember.

Comment: Did you check all the requirements? Additionally to the other ones you have to install cython to build from the source on github.

Comment: cython is installed already. Not aware of other missing except the msvccompiler

Answer (score 3):

After installing the `scipy` following the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found) , the `statsmodels` was installed successfully.