# Issue installing Keras with tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, scipy, keras, anaconda

I was trying to run spyder with tensorflow-gpu and managed to setup tensorflow-gpu through conda in anaconda prompt. However post this step when i try to install keras, i get the following error:

```
(tenserflow-gpu) C:\Users\Nithin\Documents>pip install keras
Collecting keras
  Downloading Keras-2.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (276kB)
    100% |################################| 276kB 161kB/s
Collecting scipy>=0.14 (from keras)
  Downloading scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz (14.1MB)
    100% |################################| 14.1MB 465kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\nithin\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\users\nithin\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages (from keras)
Collecting pyyaml (from keras)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.12-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (195kB)
    100% |################################| 204kB 308kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ju_zavf1\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuhtgm8rppip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  openblas_lapack_info:
  C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:655: UserWarning: Specified path c:\opt\64\lib is invalid.
    return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
    libraries libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy not found in []
    NOT AVAILABLE
  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  atlas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE
  Running from scipy source directory.
  non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ju_zavf1\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)
  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy, pyyaml, keras
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ju_zavf1\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9xcwjndr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    openblas_lapack_info:
    C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:655: UserWarning: Specified path c:\opt\64\lib is invalid.
      return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
      libraries libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy not found in []
      NOT AVAILABLE
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tenserflow-gpu\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE
    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tenserflow-gpu\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Nithin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ju_zavf1\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9xcwjndr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ju_zavf1\scipy\
(tenserflow-gpu) C:\Users\Nithin\Documents>
```

In conda i downgraded python to 3.5.2 from 3.6.2 as tensorflow-gpu would only work with 3.5.2.

Could some one please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your operating system??

Comment: I'm running windows 10

Comment: FYI: recently they have added support for python 3.6.x.

Comment: I ran into all sorts of issues trying to get it to run with 3.6.2 and every article i came across mentioned that tensorflow-gup is not supported with python 3.6.2. Would you recon i try to reinstall everything again?

Comment: I'm not sure this could helps you. You can check [Installing TensorFlow on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) to make sure TF supports python 3.6.x. By the way, it seems the problem is with **scipy** not TF.

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found

Comment: Update: Thank you for the help. I reinstalled anaconda and tensorflow-gpu with python 3.6.2.