# error installing scipy using pip on windows 10

Tags: python, scipy

i am not able to install scipy library using pip and get the error

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AYUSHG~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-61f5db76\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p2803zdd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\ayush ghai\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\ayush ghai\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:655: UserWarning: Specified path c:\opt\64\lib is invalid.
  return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
  libraries libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy not found in []
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\ayush ghai\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\ayush ghai\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

Running from scipy source directory.
non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-61f5db76\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-61f5db76\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-61f5db76\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('scipy')
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('linalg')
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
    caller_level = 2)
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
    caller_level = caller_level + 1)
  File "c:\users\ayush ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
    raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

----------------------------------------
```

> Command ""c:\users\ayush
>   ghai\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;__file__='C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-61f5db76\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-p2803zdd-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AYUSHG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-61f5db76\scipy\

Comment: Dod you follow the [instructions described here](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)

Comment: wait until wednesday and you will be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed scipy in windows 10 from the whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  through pip install command in python3.6.