# Cannot install keras on Windows using Python 3.5.4

Tags: python, windows, keras

After entering:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade keras
```

I get:

> Failed building wheel for scipy
>
> numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found"

What should I do next?
(numpy is successfully installed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)

Comment: try it with `conda install -c conda-forge keras`

Comment: I tried a similar command with "conda", but the windows command prompt doesn't recognize it.  Similar to "python", it only recognizes as "py".