# Can't install scikit-learn using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to install Scikit-learn from terminal using pip and I keep getting the same error. I tried every suggestion I could find online but nothing seems to work. I already installed numpy and scipy. I can't seem to find what it's wrong.

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
          raise NotFoundError(msg)
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\python39-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppindbl3r' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\python39-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j7apkk1n\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Looks like you need a linear algebra library. Try this: https://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/

Comment: I think u should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Scipy Install: No Lapack/Blas Resources Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190534/windows-scipy-install-no-lapack-blas-resources-found)